# recursive level adding of strings

Tags: php, recursion

I am figting with a recursion and cannot solve it. Here is what I want to do:

There are n levels. Every level has arrays of some values.

```
levels
0 => array (2)
    0 => "66:" 
    1 => "68:"
1 => array (4)
    0 => "76:9"
    1 => "76:10"
    2 => "76:13" 
    3 => "76:14"
2 => array (4)
    0 => "77:11" 
    1 => "77:12" 
    2 => "77:15"
    3 => "77:16"
```

In example that you can see upper there are 3 levels(n possible). What I am trying to do is to make combinations like this:

```
Level[0][0] + ";" + Level[1][0] + ";" + Level[2][0]
Level[0][0] + ";" + Level[1][0] + ";" + Level[2][1]
Level[0][0] + ";" + Level[1][0] + ";" + Level[2][2]
Level[0][0] + ";" + Level[1][0] + ";" + Level[2][3]
Level[0][0] + ";" + Level[1][1] + ";" + Level[2][0]
Level[0][0] + ";" + Level[1][1] + ";" + Level[2][1]
Level[0][0] + ";" + Level[1][1] + ";" + Level[2][2]
Level[0][0] + ";" + Level[1][1] + ";" + Level[2][3]

....

Level[0][1] + ";" + Level[1][3] + ";" + Level[2][3]
```

Generaly

```
Level[0][k] + ";" + Level[1][k] + ";" + Level[2][k] + ... + Level[n][k]
```

Does somebody know how to make it recursive or even non-recursive?

Comment: So, you want every possible combination?

Comment: yes, accross all levels